# Node.js and express cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to build a node backend for android app and having some problems with it.
When connecting to localhost:8080, I always get cannot GET /.

Here is my code for app.js:

```
/** Dependencies **/
var express = require('express');
var connect = require('connect');
var app     = express();
var port    = process.env.PORT || 8080;

//Configurations
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(connect.logger('dev'));
app.use(connect.json());
app.use(connect.urlencoded());

//Routes

require('./routes/routes.js');

app.listen(port);
console.log("The App is running on port " + port);
```

This is the route.js file:

```
var app     = module.exports ;

module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.end("Node-Android");
    });
}
```

Still I am getting the Cannot GET / every time trying to go to localhost:8080/

Am I missing something or have I done something horribly wrong? 
Hope I get help from here guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `routes.js` module declares a constructor function that requires an argument (the `app` object) with this line:

```
module.exports = function(app){ ... }
```

But, you are just including the module like this:

```
require('./routes/routes.js');
```

That means you're just loading the module, but never calling the constructor.  So, instead, you need to change this:

```
require('./routes/routes.js');
```

to this:

```
require('./routes/routes.js')(app);
```

That will call the constructor and pass it the desired `app` object that it can then use to initialize its routes.

---

In addition, you have a misleading and unnecessary line of code in your module where you do this:

```
var app     = module.exports ;
```

That particular `app` variable is not used anywhere in your module and it's misleading because it has the same name as the `app` parameter to your constructor function.  You should just remove that line from the routes.js module.  It is misleading and unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I got it to work now !

Comment: @OskarMartin - Since it looks like you may be new here, if your question has been answered, then you should click the green checkmark next to the best answer.  That will indicate to the community that your question has been answered and will earn you a few reputation points for following the proper procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up !

Answer (score 2):

```
require('./routes/routes.js');
```

should be

`require('./routes/routes.js')(app)`;